# Emacs align-regexp on = but not ==

Tags: emacs, haskell, elisp, alignment

I am working in Haskell and frequently come across code similar to the following:

```
func i j | i == j = i
         | otherwise = j
```

I want to align on the '=' character using align-regexp but don't have the elisp knowhow.  I have tried just doing " = " without the quotes, but this inserts an unwanted space character before each '='.  I have found a proposed solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669625/emacs-align-regexp-working-with) but I can't seem to get that to do anything at all.

Please help me write a function or hard-coded macro that will allow me to set a keybinding for this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

<kbd>C-u M-x</kbd> `align-regexp` <kbd>RET</kbd> `\(\s-*\) =` <kbd>RET</kbd> `1` <kbd>RET</kbd> `0` <kbd>RET</kbd> `n`

(n.b. there's a space after the '=', but it's not very obvious.)

Which is to say...

Use a prefix argument to tell `align-regexp` to ask you for more parameters than it does by default.

See <kbd>C-h f</kbd> `align-regexp` and <kbd>C-h v</kbd> `align-rules-list` for details, but in short:

`\(\s-*\)` is the default 'group' for deletion/expansion. We append our pattern to the end of that: ' = '. (Note that `\s-` is Emacs regexp syntax for whitespace.)

`1` simply refers to parenthesised group 1 (as above). This is the default.

`0` for the spacing to use between the two parts of the line. By default this is 1, and is why you were ending up with an additional space.

`n` to not align any subsequent pattern matches after the first in each line.

edit: Actually, the Q&A you linked to is near identical, and works fine for me on Emacs 23.2.1, so this *is* a duplicate, but to continue and answer the key-binding aspect:

You can bind that (or any) sequence via keyboard macros. Here's the end result, which you can probably just add to your init file, although I recommend you go through the process yourself. Use whatever you like in place of `C-c a` for the key. `C-c (letter)` and F5-F9 are reserved for end-users to bind as they please, so one of those will be safe from being clobbered by a mode's keymap.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c a") (lambda (&optional arg) "Keyboard macro." (interactive "p") (kmacro-exec-ring-item (quote ([21 134217848 97 108 105 103 110 45 114 101 103 101 120 112 return 32 61 32 return return backspace 48 return 110] 0 "%d")) arg)))
```

I did that by:

1. selecting the text.
2. <kbd>F3</kbd> to start recording.
3. performing the `align-regexp` as above (being careful to type everything verbatim, and not use minibuffer history or yanking).<sup>1</sup>
4. <kbd>F4</kbd> to stop recording.
5. <kbd>C-x C-k n</kbd> `align-single-equals` <kbd>RET</kbd> to give the macro a name
6. <kbd>M-x</kbd> `insert-kbd-macro` <kbd>RET</kbd> `align-single-equals` <kbd>RET</kbd> to get the lisp.
7. Wrapping the `(lambda)` expression with `(global-set-key)` to bind it. (Although you could also use the `(fset 'align-single-equals ...)` code as provided, and then bind the key to that symbol.

<sup>1</sup> If you make a mistake when recording a complicated macro, don't fret — Emacs provides a really good macro editor which you can use to fix any mistakes after you finish recording (just type <kbd>C-x C-k e</kbd>), so you don't need to be perfect.

edit 2: May as well add an example of a function, as per comments.

```
(defun my-align-single-equals ()
  "Align on a single equals sign (with a space either side)."
  (interactive)
  (align-regexp
   (region-beginning) (region-end)
   "\\(\\s-*\\) = " 1 0 nil))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c a") 'my-align-single-equals)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to use your solution but created a function instead of a macro, as it's more readable for me.

Comment: Well that's even better :) A function is definitely preferable if you're happy writing lisp, but macros are very handy if you're not.

Comment: a bit late to the party, but the canonical way to solve this is to add a rule to `align-rules-list' instead of writing your own function.